# force to answer Alert dialog after onBackPressed()

Tags: java, android, back

I'm developing a game, and during the gameplay I want to prevent user from missusing the back button, so when the backbutton is pressed insted of finishing the activity, an alert dialog is shown asking if they really want to go back. If they answer "yes", the activity finishes, if they answer "no" the dialog disapear and they can continue with the game.
The problem is that if they touch again the back button or if they press anywhere out of the alert dialog, it disapears and they can continue playing, but without executing the code that I've implemented in the negative answer to continue playing, so the background color of the buttons doesnt restore to the original color and the countdowntimmer doesnt starts

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                botones[i].setBackgroundColor(0xff000000);
            }
            //storage of variables, nothing to do with the question
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setTitle(getString(R.string.AlertaSalirPartida))
                    .setMessage(getString(R.string.AlertaSalirPartidaPregunta))
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                                botones[i].setBackgroundColor(0xff58d3f7);
                            }
                            //starting a countdowntimer, nothing to do with the question

                        }
                    })
                    .show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your dialog non-cancelable like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setCanceledOnOutsideTouch(false);
```

In addition, you can check `setOnDismissListener` and `setOnCanceledListener`

setCancelable and setCanceledOnOutsideTouch should make it unable to close the dialog onbackpressed, otherwise one of the listeners will be called.

Comment: Thanks that worked, but I only had to put `.setCancelable(false)`